# Invalid date - Momentjs

Tags: jquery, pug, momentjs

App.js

```
function updatePost(){
    last_updated = new Date()
    ...
}
```

Jade template

```
.date
 .day #{last_updated}
 .month.uppercase #{last_updated}
```

JQuery in jade template

```
var date = $('.month, .day').text()
alert(date)
var convertMonth = moment(date, "DD MMM YYYY").format("MMM")
$('.month').html(convertMonth)
var convertDay = moment(date, "DD MMM YYYY").format("D")
$('.day').html(convertDay)
```

Alert(date) returns

```
Thu Oct 30 2014 14:16:28 GMT+0800 (SGT)Thu Oct 30 2014 14:16:28 GMT+0800 (SGT)Thu Oct 30 2014 12:42:51 GMT+0800 (SGT)Thu Oct 30 2014 12:42:51 GMT+0800 (SGT)Wed Oct 29 2014 15:45:00 GMT+0800 (SGT)Wed Oct 29 2014 15:45:00 GMT+0800 (SGT)
```

The result prints repeatedly:
Invalid date
Invalid date

Everytime user saves post, the date is also updated. 
On the listing, the day and month should be reflected upon updating or creating post.

Why do I get invalid dates?

Help appreciated!

Comment: I just miss the semicolon so much :(

Comment: @mr.d - semicolon you refer to jquery part right? it is done in jade template so no need for these